# Access server files from sql server

Tags: sql-server, file

I want to check whether a file exist in an online server from sql server.
I have this code

```
exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'http://filepath'.
```

This function returns value zero for `FileExists Column`. I think this function will only work for searching files in the local system. If so ,how can I check a file exist in online server from sql server.

Comment: `xp_fileexist` really isn't meant for this type of operation, its an undocumented proc mainly meant for MS internal usage.  As for the 'how', I would really question the 'why', what are you trying to do? This operation sounds like it should be in another layer of the application.

Comment: I have written a function which need to return the filepath of user uploaded files from website to display it in mobile apps.@cjb110

Comment: none of that sounds like SQL or database related, it should be in the mobile app code, or maybe a service running on/near the database.

Comment: @cjb110 So you mean that we cannot search online files from sql server which is in other server,right??

Comment: I'm saying there is no native/built in way, and you shouldn't be attempting it anyway.  Not that you 'cant' :) You could abuse xp_cmdshell and launch an external process, or possibly using .net CLR functions.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the FileStream feature in newer versions of SQL Server.

I find this link most informative: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream

Comment: FileStream isn't a general purpose IO layer, its meant for storing large objects in the database on the filesystem.

Comment: @cjb110; yes, but it may be a way around various security problems, and it sounded on the OP that it was a specific "data type" that was needed.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a terrible idea, you shouldn't be wasting schedulers waiting for a http response. It will kill the performance of your system.
That being said, if you have no other options, and you are very careful about what and when you are doing stuff like this it actually is possible using ole automation.

First you need to enable ole automation using

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Then you can use xmlhttp to fetch the url

Something along the lines of

```
sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT
```

will create a [msxml2.xmlhttp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923283.aspx) object

You can then call all methods defined in that object such as

```
sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', 'http://myurl', false
```

You will have to read up on the object and play around with it for a while, but it certainly is possible